# Logical AND and logical OR operator precedence

Tags: java

Logical AND `&&` has higher precedence than logical OR `||`.

This is simple java code http://ideone.com/KWUOla

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        if( A() || B() && C() && D() ){
            System.out.println("done...");
        }
    }
    public static boolean A(){
        System.out.println("This is class A");
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean B(){
        System.out.println("This is class B");
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean C(){
        System.out.println("This is class C");
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean D(){
        System.out.println("This is class D");
        return true;
    }    
}
```

In this program function `A()` is completing first then OR is evaluated and since the left operand is true the if condition is satisfied.

But as per the precedence table all logical AND `&&` should be evaluated before the evaluation of logical OR `||`.

Does Java have the same priority for logical AND `&&` and logical OR `||`? If not, please clarify the precedence order between logical AND `&&` and logical OR `||`.

Comment: Don't confuse precedence with associativity.

Comment: Don't be parentheses averse the compiler will optimize regardless.

Comment: Also, [running this myself](http://ideone.com/SslQYc) just shows `This is class A`, then `done...`. Strange. Not sure how you got your result...

Comment: Think of ```&&``` and ```||``` like ```*``` and ```+```.  ```a + b * c * d = a + (b * c * d)```. But since you're using methods, remember that logical operators short circuit as soon as the result is known, so both ```false && foo()``` and ```true || foo()``` never call ```foo```.

Comment: associativity is order of execution (either from left to right or from right to left) of same operator. But If we have operator of higher precedence in expression then operator having higher precedence should be evaluated first. Here logical And(&&) have higher precedence but it is not evaluated first.

Comment: You're still confusing precedence with associativity. Precedence affects grouping. Things are still evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precedence rules remove the ambiguity by effectively adding brackets:

```
A() || ((B() && C()) && D())
```

And brackets don't affect the order of execution which is **always** left to right.

Then as you say, it doesn't need to calculate the right hand side of the or as the left hand side is true. (This is called short circuiting).

Answer (score 0):

It runs only A() because it returns true. I strongly recommend to use parenthesises.

Comment: Not true. See my comment on the question. Only `A()` should evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, @user3580294. Found that Operator associativity is different from precedence. That helped!

Comment: Yep, it's confusing at times. You should fix your answer so you aren't wrong.

Comment: Still not quite there. Only `A()` should run -- it appears something's off with OP's example...

Comment: which means the result of ideone.com is wrong?

Comment: If you look at the link I posted in the comments section, copy/pasting OP's code and running it again yields different results. I have no clue how OP got the results he did.

Comment: I got it. Because the return value of A() is true, the others are not running. Thanks.