# Java Logical Operator And/Or Precedence

Tags: java, logic, operators

So everywhere I look, it says that && is evaluated first, then || is evaluated second. So either I am doing something wrong or it is wrong. Here's the code:

```
static boolean foo(boolean b, int id){ System.out.println(id); return b;}

static{ System.out.println(foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1) || foo(false, 2)) }
//returns 3 1

static{ System.out.println(foo(true, 2) || foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1)} 
//returns 2
```

In the first static block, && goes first, short circuits and ignores the || but in the second static block which is simply the reverse, || goes first and ignored the &&. This demonstrates left to right but according to the java doc, && has higher precedence which means && should always go first.

Some documents about precedence (logical **and** is higher than **or**):
1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html
2. https://chortle.ccsu.edu/Java5/Notes/chap40/ch40_16.html
3. http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html
...

Comment: It's evaluated left to right... not sure where you are looking.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry I forgot the second static. I reversed the && and || and it evaluated || first as if it is left to right.

Comment: I think what's happening is that the logic is being short-circuited.  It's normal when evaluating `||` that once a `true` is obtained, then the rest of the expression doesn't need to be evaluated, because it's already `true`.  Let us know if you were thinking something different.

Comment: Some more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Comment: And also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: @markspace yeah it would short circuit if the precedence or || is higher then &&… but since || is less than && it should look at && next regardless of the short circuit. Doesn't that only occur when the || is to actually be evaluated.

Comment: No I don't think that's correct.  Even if && is higher, it's still true that as long as the left side of || is true, then the whole expression is true.  In some ways I think you have it backwards.  Because && has higher precedence, that means || goes last and then controls the final outcome.  Work it out with a truth table and see if I'm correct.

Comment: P. S. And remember, short-circuit evaluation requires that the left side be evaluated first, so that's what the || and && are doing.  That's why you get two outputs for the first one and only one for the second.

Comment: @markspace higher precedence does mean going first. In the table */ has higher precedence than +- so that is not backwards. However, ill look into this weird short circuiting enigma. Maybe it is smart enough to just skip the rest regardless of precedence.

Comment: Logical boolean expressions don't work exactly the same way as multiplication and addition.  Basically, yes, the optimizer can determine that parts of the expression can be skipped, and short circuit requires that they are skipped.  So it's just part of the spec.

Comment: Too much confusion here. 1. The *operands* are evaluated left to right. 2. The *operators* are evaluated according to precedence. 3. The RHS of `&&` isn't evaluated if the LHS is false. 4. The RHS of `||` isn't evaluated if the LHS is true.

Comment: @markspace  It is the defined behaviour of these operators in the JLS. It has nothing to do with 'the optimizer' whatsoever.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620919/why-does-the-or-go-before-the-and

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602875/logical-and-and-logical-or-operator-precedence

Answer (score 1):

Higher predecence of `&&` just means that

```
foo(true, 2) || foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1)
```

is the same as

```
foo(true, 2) || (foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1))
```

but not

```
(foo(true, 2) || foo(true, 3)) && foo(true, 1)
```

Nothing else. It doesn't imply anything about evaluation order.

Now, for most operators, evaluating `x op y` requires evaluating both `x` and `y`. If `||` was one of them, it would be the same as (`return` is from evaluating `||`, not from the entire method)

```
boolean tmp1 = foo(true, 2);
boolean tmp2 = foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1);
return tmp1 || tmp2;
```

and `&&` would indeed "go first". But there are three operators which don't work like that: `&&`, `||` and `?:`. Instead you get

```
boolean tmp1 = foo(true, 2);
if (tmp1) {
    return true; 
} else {
    return foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1);
}
```

Comment: I understand the point of short-circuiting. It does not evaluate the right side if it can guarantee the complete evaluation is true. But foo(true, 2) || (foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1)) -> && first because it has more parenthesis right? For example: a + (b + (c + d)) where (a, b, c, d) = (1, 2, 3, 4) -> 1 + (2 + (3 + 4)) -> 1 + (2 + 7) -> 1 + 9 -> 10

Comment: Can you give me an example where || then && left to right does && first?

Comment: "But foo(true, 2) || (foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1)) -> && first because it has more parenthesis right? For example: a + (b + (c + d))" No. Left-hand side `foo(true, 2)` first, then `foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1)` _if necessary_ (and it isn't). If `||` and `&&` didn't short-circuit, the order would be: 1. `foo(true, 2)`; 2. `foo(true, 3)`; 3. `foo(true, 1)`; 4. `&&`; 5. `||`. But they do.

Comment: "Can you give me an example where || then && left to right does && first?" Just change `true`s to `false`. But even then: 1. `foo(false, 2)` gets executed first, before `&&`. 2. you could say `&&` is evaluated inside `||`, not before it. But it finishes before `||` does.

Comment: That does not execute && first. It returns 2 3 1 where 2 is on the left of or. That still executes || first.

Comment: Then `a() + b() * c()` doesn't execute `*` first, because it'll start with `a()` (just like `a() || b() && c()`).

Comment: foo(false, 2) || foo(true, 3) && foo(true, 1) -> 2 3 1 tested still does || first

Comment: I really don't know how to explain it any simpler. What you are checking is that it evaluates the left-hand side of `||` first. But the same will happen for any operators at all, whatever their precedence is (and whether they short-circuit or not). But `&&` _finishes_ before `||` does (in this example).